# ggplot vertical line with date axis R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, vline

I'm having problems ploting vertical lines with ggplot in R.

I want to draw a vertical line each Sunday on my time serie:

```
VisitDate VisitMonth VisitYear      City   Weekday VisitWeek Code_CxF               Centre  Location
1 2014-05-02           05        2014 Barcelona    05Friday  2014-04-28  CxF_BCN CaixaForum Barcelona Catalunya
2 2014-05-03           05        2014 Barcelona  06Saturday  2014-04-28  CxF_BCN CaixaForum Barcelona Catalunya
3 2014-05-04           05        2014 Barcelona    07Sunday  2014-04-28  CxF_BCN CaixaForum Barcelona Catalunya
4 2014-05-06           05        2014 Barcelona   02Tuesday  2014-05-05  CxF_BCN CaixaForum Barcelona Catalunya
5 2014-05-07           05        2014 Barcelona 03Wednesday  2014-05-05  CxF_BCN CaixaForum Barcelona Catalunya
6 2014-05-08           05        2014 Barcelona  04Thursday  2014-05-05  CxF_BCN CaixaForum Barcelona Catalunya
```

I have tried the following expression:

```
ggplot(data = MUSEUS_PLOT, aes(x = VisitDate, y = Visitors.x)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.25, aes(x = VisitDate, y = Visitors.x, colour = "CxF")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Visitors.y, colour = "MNAC")) + 
  labs(title = "MONTJUICH May 2014", x = "Day", y = "Visitors") +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",values=c(CxF="darkcyan", MNAC="darkorange2")) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = which(weekdays(MUSEUS_PLOT$VisitDate) == "Sunday")))
```

But it is not working:

```
Error in data.frame(xintercept = c(3L, 9L, 15L, 21L), PANEL = c(1L, 1L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 26
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new data table with the sundays data:

```
MUSEUS_PLOT_SUNDAYS <- MUSEUS_PLOT[weekdays(MUSEUS_PLOT$VisitDate) == "Sunday"]
```

And change the geom_vline for this:

```
  geom_vline(data = MUSEUS_PLOT_SUNDAYS,aes(xintercept = as.numeric(VisitDate)),colour = "black")
```